# How to check only selected checkbox and get it's value in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use React Native to create a group of checkbox that allow users to choose the option they may like. But I am having problem that all the checkbox is checked at the same time and unable to get it's value. For checkboxes I use this package [react-native-circle-checkbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-circle-checkbox) Here is my code:

```
class Answer extends Component {
  constructor(prop) {
    super(prop);

    this.state = {
      checked: false,
      checkboxValue: [
        {
          label: "Option1",
          value: 1
        },
        {
          label: "Option2",
          value: 2
        },
        {
          label: "Option3",
          value: 3
        },
        {
          label: "Option4",
          value: 4
        },
        {
          label: "Option5",
          value: 5
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  CheckMe = (value, index) => {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    });
    console.log(index);
  };

  render() {
    const options = this.state.checkboxValue;

    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <View style={styles.questionWrapper}>
          <View style={styles.questionGroup}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
              {options.map(option => {
                return (
                  <CircleCheckBox
                    key={option.value}
                    checked={this.state.checked}
                    onToggle={(value, index) => this.CheckMe()}
                    labelPosition={LABEL_POSITION.RIGHT}
                    label={option.label}
                    styleLabel={{ fontSize: 17 }}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I want when a user check on a checkbox only that checkbox is checked and get it's value.

How can I do that?

Comment: Radio Button is best suited for this
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure that only one option is selected it would be more natural to use radio-buttons. But you can achieve that with checkboxes too:

```
class Answer extends Component {
  constructor(prop) {
    super(prop);

    this.state = {
      selectedCheckbox: {}, // keep selected item in state, by default its empty meaning nothing is selected
      checkboxValue: [
        {
          label: "Option1",
          value: 1
        },
        {
          label: "Option2",
          value: 2
        },
        {
          label: "Option3",
          value: 3
        },
        {
          label: "Option4",
          value: 4
        },
        {
          label: "Option5",
          value: 5
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  CheckMe = selectedCheckbox => {
    this.setState({ selectedCheckbox }); // update selected item
  };

  render() {
    const { checkboxValue, selectedCheckbox } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <View style={styles.questionWrapper}>
          <View style={styles.questionGroup}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
              {checkboxValue.map((option, indexInArray) => {
                return (
                  <CircleCheckBox
                    key={option.value}
                    checked={option.value === selectedCheckbox.value} // for current element
                    onToggle={(value, index) => this.CheckMe(option)} // pass index of toggled element
                    labelPosition={LABEL_POSITION.RIGHT}
                    label={option.label}
                    styleLabel={{ fontSize: 17 }}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tomasz Mularczyk but how can we can the checked one uncheck when the other is checked?

Comment: So only one checkbox can be selected?

Comment: Yes I want like that :)

Comment: Ohh, then you should use radio-buttons for something like that. But I can make checkboxes work like this also. One sec...

Comment: @DooDoo should be fine now.